# Deleting Spanned Volume on File Server between Disk 1 & Disk 2

Tags: file-server, disk-volume

I have Windows Server 2012 R2 and it is my file server and it auto syncs user's file every minute. I have 3 disks. The primary partition (Disk 0) and two others (Disk 1 & Disk 2). My question does not include the primary partition.

I shrunk Disk 2 so that I had unallocated space. I then extended Disk 1 using the unallocated space from Disk 2 creating spanned volume on Disk 1 (extended volume on Disk 2). It did not do what I wanted so I want to 'undo' it. Can I just delete the spanned volume on Disk 2 (space that added to Disk 1)? Or more accurately if I'm going to delete the spanned volume on Disk 2, will it affect my users' files?